# Field over irrationals

Tags: field-theory, irrational-numbers

Is it possible to construct a field over the irrationals?

The problem is to define two binary operations that satisfy the axioms of a field.

The regular multiplication and addition operators fail to satisfy these axioms. For example:

**Multiplication:**
$$\sqrt{2}\cdot \sqrt{2}=2\notin\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q}$$

**Addion:**
$$\sqrt{2}-\sqrt{2}=0\notin\mathbb{R}\setminus\mathbb{Q} $$

Do you have an example?

Comment: Take any bijection $\;f:\Bbb R\to Irr\;$,  and define on $\;Irr\;$ the operations $\;a+b:=f(a'+b') \;$ and likewise for multiplication, when $\;a',b',\in\Bbb R\;$ are the only elements in $\;\Bbb R\;$ s.t. $\;f(a')=a,\,f(b')=b\;$ ...This is a very boring way to construct algebraic structures over otherwise weird sets.

Comment: If you have no particular requirement then you surely can create a field from any set with the same cardinality as any known field (see DonAntonio's comment).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1687296/define-group-structure-on-mathbbr-setminus-q/1687333#1687333